# Redux newbie attempting to make chrome extension work

Tags: redux, google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a solution to Redux token import (of which I only learned today). I am attempting to write a Redux expression into a chrome extension called "Highlight This" (found here https://www.highlightthis.net/).

It appears the extension takes Redux "tokens", whatever that might be, and I need it to highlight a filed only if populated and have attempted to wrap my head around the expression would be and got as far as probably needs to be a if/then but not much further than that as I have absolutely no previous experience with Redux expressions.

I need the extension to highlight a specific field that happens in the middle of a page, and the filed is either blank or has a date.

Looks like this:

| description | value |
| --- | --- |
| Irrelevant 1 | `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM` |
| Most Recent Flag Time | `blank` or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM` |
| Irrelevant 2 | `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM` |

If someone can either point me in the right direction of what I should look at to write my own expression or show me an example I want to basically have the extension check the field right after "Most Recent Flag Time" and if it contains anything to simply highlight that date as it would as if I gave it a specific word to search and highlight automatically.